# Searchbar on Nav bar not showing on viewdidload()

Tags: ios, swift

I can't seem to force the search bar that is embedded inside a search controller to show up when the view controller initially loads. I have tried adding `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false` when does force the search bar to appear when loaded but then it makes the `title` small. Is there a way to make it so searchbar appears with a large title?

The code and pictures are below to show what I mean.

```
import Moya
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class MeetingsViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private var searchController: UISearchController?
    private var provider = MoyaProvider<NewLyfe>()
    private var meetings: [Meeting]? {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSearchController()
        setupBarItems()
        updateViews()
    }

}

// MARK: - private functions

extension MeetingsViewController {
    private func setupSearchController() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
        let searchResultController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withClass: SearchResultTableViewController.self)

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
        searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "neighborhood, city, state, or zip code"
        searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultController
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    }

    private func setupBarItems() {
        let mapIcon = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "map.fill"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentMapModal))
        mapIcon.tintColor = .systemGreen
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = mapIcon

        let filterIcon = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "slider.horizontal.3"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentFilterModal))
        filterIcon.tintColor = .systemGreen
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = filterIcon
    }

    private func updateViews() {
        let realm = try? Realm()
        let filterOptions = realm?.objects(FilterOptions.self).first
        searchController?.searchBar.text = filterOptions?.name
        fetchMeetings(using: filterOptions)
    }

    private func fetchMeetings(using filterOptions: FilterOptions?) {
        guard let options = filterOptions, let lat = options.latitude.value, let long = options.longitude.value else { return }
        provider.request(.meetings(day: "Sun", program: "AA", region: "\(lat),\(long),10")) { (result) in
            switch result {

            case .success(let response):
                do {
                    self.meetings = try response.map([Meeting].self)
                } catch let error {
                    print("Error decoding meetings: \(error)")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching meetings: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}

// MARK: - @objc functions

extension MeetingsViewController {
    @objc func presentFilterModal() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "presentFilterModal", sender: nil)
    }

    @objc func presentMapModal() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "presentMapModal", sender: nil)
    }

}

// MARK: - Table view data source/delegate

extension MeetingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return meetings?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "meetingCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(meetings?[indexPath.row].name ?? "")"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(meetings?[indexPath.row].day ?? "")"

        return cell
    }

}

// MARK: - Search bar delegate

extension MeetingsViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        updateViews()
    }

}
```

Here's how I want it to look like:

[image]

Here's how it currently looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I was having the same problem and I fixed it by adding `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false` to what would be my `setupSearchController` function.
So in your case the function would look like this:

```
private func setupSearchController() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main)
    let searchResultController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withClass: SearchResultTableViewController.self)

    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultController)
    searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "neighborhood, city, state, or zip code"
    searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultController
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

}
```